# Get the division result and group by chanel from two calculated tables sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I have two SELECT statements.
In those statements there is a month, Source and calculating count.

What I'm trying to do is to get the result of a division from these two tables grouped by SOURCE.

And when I do the grouping, I'm getting NULL for the calculation part.
I guess the reason is that going through the months tables are not the same.

For example for the date 201901 there is a source A, but for 201801 there isn't because it didn't exist in that time.

I'm not sure whether I should use JOIN, UNION or anything else.

I know that I'm probably missing something obvious. 
Could you please help me with the code?

```
-- WHAT I'VE ALREADY TRIED
--SELECT * 
--FROM t2,t1
--GROUP BY t2.month_id,t1.month_id,t2.PREF_ORDER_SOURCE,t1.PREF_ORDER_SOURCE
--ORDER BY t2.month_id,t1.month_id,t2.PREF_ORDER_SOURCE,t1.PREF_ORDER_SOURCE

WITH t1 as (
SELECT 
cust.month_id, 
count(*) as AB_P1_TOTAL,
CASE 
When CODE='A' then 'AURA'
When CODE='B' then 'SHOP'
When CODE in ('NS','T','CN1','CN2','CO1','CO2','1С') then 'CLUB'
When CODE in ('I','I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6') then 'Internet'
ELSE CODE

end as SOURCE

FROM CUS_T cust
JOIN CUSTOMER dcust ON dcust.month_id=cust.month_id and 
dcust.cust_srcid=cust.cust_srcid
WHERE   
cust.month_id ='$P-p_ly_parameter'

group by cust.month_id,
CASE 
When CODE='A' then 'AURA'
When CODE='B' then 'SHOP'
When CODE in ('NS','T','CN1','CN2','CO1','CO2','1С') then 'CLUB'
When CODE in ('I','I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6') then 'Internet'
ELSE CODE

end


),

t2 as (
SELECT 
cust.month_id, 
count(*)as AB_P2_TOTAL,
CASE 
When CODE='A' then 'AURA'
When CODE='B' then 'SHOP'
When CODE in ('NS','T','CN1','CN2','CO1','CO2','1С') then 'CLUB'
When CODE in ('I','I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6') then 'Internet'
ELSE CODE

end as SOURCE

FROM CUS_T cust
JOIN CUSTOMER dcust ON dcust.month_id=cust.month_id and 
dcust.cust_srcid=cust.cust_srcid
WHERE 
cust.month_id ='$P-p_current_parameter'

group by 

cust.month_id,
CASE 
When CODE='A' then 'AURA'
When CODE='B' then 'SHOP'
When CODE in ('NS','T','CN1','CN2','CO1','CO2','1С') then 'CLUB'
When CODE in ('I','I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6') then 'Internet'
ELSE CODE

end 
)

SELECT 
SOURCE, 
1-(t2.AB_P2_TOTAL)/t1.AB_P1_TOTAL
```

I expect the division grouped by chanel

```
month_id    SOURCE  Result
201807          Internet  1.15
201807          CLUB      2.12
201808          Internet  3.24
201808          CLUB      4.52
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

It Depends on what kind of a result you are expecting:

If t1 is 0/NULL, what do you want to do?
If t2 is 0/NULL, what do you want to do?

Depending on the answers to the above question, you can write case statements to get the desired result. I am sorry if this answer did not help. But we would have to clarify the above questions before proceeding.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, if for example in 201901 for the source Internet there was a value and for 201801 there was no value, I expect it to be not calculated (zero or NULL).

If t1 is 0/NULL or t2 is 0/NULL - no calculations are expected (zero or NULL are fine).